# android AutoCompleteTextView seems to ignore the Filter of the custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

All I want to do is displaying a CheckBox at each result of the AutoCompleteTextView's results (which are strings).

I wrote an custom Array Adapter which implements Filterable. I added a simple Filter wich gets called (I checked that) and returns the expected results. However the displayed results are completely different ones.

Here is my Filter-Code:

```
private class MyFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if ((constraint == null) || (constraint.length() == 0))
            {
                synchronized (mLock)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                String constr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                final ArrayList<String> newItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String temp : items)
                {
                    if (temp.toLowerCase().startsWith((constr)))
                    {
                        newItems.add(temp);
                    }
                }
                results.values = newItems;
                results.count = newItems.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results)
        {
            if (results.count > 0)
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
```

Do I miss something?
Thank you!

Comment: I think we'd need to see some code. Is it possible though that you are returning the complement of the results you need? In other words, are the results you're getting the complete *opposite* of the ones you want?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I pasted in my filter code. Unfortunately the filter is returning those items that I want, so it it probably not the complement.

Comment: The error might be in your adapter then...

Comment: I forgot to set the results as the new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to set my results as the new items of the adapter.